# How to observe multiple data of same class in Java observable (MVC)?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, observable

Here's 2 option that i thought of.

1. Have multiple models each representing one class. If i have 2 int
   object, i need to create 2 observable and have view checking which
   observable is changed.
2. In a single observable (model), group multiple object of the same
   class into Array. In view i will have to iterate the array and
   change all fields containing all data in the array.

I am starting to learn how to implement MVC pattern, using java observable and observer. I find the 2 methods which i have mentioned is not the best solution. Hope can get some help on this.

**Edit:**
Example, i have the following methods in observable class, can someone show me how to write the update() in observer to get the value of int b?

```
public void setIntA(int a){
     this.intA = a;
     setChanged();
     notifyObservers(a);
}
public void setIntB(int b){
     this.intB = b;
     setChanged();
     notifyObservers(b);
}
setIntA(5);
setIntB(3);
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. But note that Observers get two parameters in their notification, the target Observable and an optional extra object that is entirely up to you. Maybe you can make use of that (for example to pass the field name).

Comment: Did you find any answer to this @phatez?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do here but if you have a class that extends Observable then it can fire a change event for any number of reasons. If you just want to notify observers when any value changes then you just need to call setChanged() and notifyObservers() in the setter. 
Like Thilo said, you can pass the thing that changed as a parameter of 
notifyObservers();

```
public void setIntA(int a){
     this.intA = a;
     setChanged();
     notifyObservers(a);
}
```

I suggest you make sure you read the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) thoroughly to get the best understanding of Observer and Observable.

Comment: yup i understand this. But what if i want to setIntB. After i notifyObservers(b), when i call update() in observer, how do i know if the value is from int a or b?

Comment: you could call `notifyObservers("a")`

Comment: You should do `notifyObservers(this)` and your observers can call `getIntA();getIntB();`to see the updated values. Is that what you mean? Another approach would be to use an event enum (A_UPDATED, B_UPDATED) or object heirachy for events like is used in Swing/AWT. I think if this doesn't meet your requirements you are probably trying to approach the overall problem in the wrong way. It's difficult to help further without some more context.

Answer (score 0):

Create two references on the Observer class to a and be and you can use update command like this.

```
public void update(Observable o, Object arg)
{
  if (o == a)
  {
     //do what you want with arg
  }
}
```