# Observable Notify Multiple variables change

Tags: android, observable, observers

How I can Notify on Multiple variables update?

Is there any method to detect and separatenotifyObservers?

```
public class AnimalWeightObservable extends Observable {

    public long animalId;

    public long weigh;

    public long getAnimalId() {
        return animalId;
    }

    public AnimalWeightObservable setAnimalId(long animalId) {
        this.animalId = animalId;
        this.setChanged();
        this.notifyObservers(animalId);
        return this;
    }

    public long getWeigh() {
        return weigh;
    }

    public AnimalWeightObservable setWeigh(long weigh) {
        this.weigh = weigh;
        this.setChanged();
        this.notifyObservers(weigh);
        return this;
    }

}
```

How can detect witch variable has changed?

Comment: see if this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/11984753/3321991

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about wrapping `animalId` and `weight` inside another type: for example `AnimalProperty`

```
class AnimalProperty<T> {
    String propertyName;
    T property;

    AnimalProperty(String name, T property) {
        this.propertyName = name;
        this.property = property;
    }
}
```

so your code would look like this:

```
public class AnimalWeightObservable extends Observable {

    public AnimalProperty animalId;

    public AnimalProperty weigh;

    //...
    //...

    public AnimalWeightObservable setWeigh(AnimalProperty weigh) {
        this.weigh = weigh;
        this.setChanged();
        this.notifyObservers(weigh);
        return this;
    }
}
```

then in the `Observer`'s `update(...)` method switch on the `propertyName` to know which property is updated

Comment: That's a Brilliant Idea, I was thinkin about ** this.notifyObservers("ID"+id)**, but not a clean code, Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome. P.S, consider making your properties private :)

Comment: That's because of ORM ;)